Landing in Grub shell while starting Ubuntu - Grub can't see all drives
I have installed Ubuntu beside Win10. Both are installed to their own hard drive. When I try to load Ubuntu I land in the Grub shell and Grub does only see the Win10 hard drive but not the Ubuntu one.
The bootloader for Ubuntu was installed on the Ubuntu hard drive while installing the OS. Because of this, it seemed strange that Grub doesn't recognize the drive on which it is installed.
What is curious is the fact that if I swap in the boot menu of the motherboard UEFI from Ubuntu to the Win bootloader, Win10 loads just fine. If I shut Win10 down swap in the motherboard UEFI boot menu back to Ubuntu, Ubuntu will start. After Ubuntu Starts it will ask me first if I want to load Ubuntu or the Win10 bootloader. But if I shutdown Ubuntu and try to start it again I land in the Grub shell again.
In the motherboard UEFI boot menue I have 4 options. Ubuntu, UEFI OS, Win Bootloader and SSD1(which is the win10 ssd) When I select Win10 it starts Win10 just fine. When I select Ubuntu the above mentioned happens. Therefore it starts only when Win10 was active on the last start. When I chose UEFI OS I land on the Ubuntu startup menue (I think this is a grub interface) were I can chose Ubuntu or the Win10 bootloader. From there all works fine. The strange thing is now, if I load Ubuntu and shut down, on the next start it changes the first boot option in the motherboard UEFI back to ubuntu which results in the grub shell who does not recognizes any other harddrive but the Win10 one.
